# Creating a class S4 class in R with a Zoo object attribute

Tags: r, class, zoo, r-s4

I would like to create a new time series class with an attribute being a Zoo object.
Unfortunately, the "zoo" class is not recognised.

```
library(zoo)
setClass("timeseries", representation(ts = "zoo", name = "character"),)
Warning message:
undefined slot classes in definition of "timeseries": ts(class "zoo")
```

What should I do to create a class with a zoo object as an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Following code does the job.

```
library(zoo)
setOldClass("zoo")
setClass("timeseries", representation(ts = "zoo", name = "character"))
```